# Arduino CSS RGB hex color parsing in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

I'm using ESP8266 to run my smart room over MQTT.
I'm struggling with converting a string to separated RGB integer values.
The string I get looks like this: `#953f4f`

I've already tried `toInt()`, `atoi()`, `atol()`, casting, etc.

Here is the code:

```
    mqtt.subscribe("light/rgb", [] (const String &payload) {
        char msg[payload.length() + 1];
        payload.toCharArray(msg, payload.length() + 1);
        int r = msg[1];
        Serial.println(r);
    });
```

Now I need to find out how to convert ASCII to int.
Unless there's a better way to convert string to an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Arduino has [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) then you can do it like this:

```
mqtt.subscribe("light/rgb", [] (const String &payload) {
    if (payload.length() != 7) {
        Serial.printf("invalid payload: '%s'\n", payload.c_str());
        return;
    }
    long rgb = strtol(payload.c_str() + 1, 0, 16); // parse as Hex, skipping the leading '#'
    int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b = rgb & 0xFF;
    Serial.printf("r=%d, g=%d, b=%d\n", r, g, b);
});
```